# 保存先のファイルパスを指定してRealmを取得する方法がわかりません

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

のところで、

```
test1
2015-08-17 07:15:03.482 test-key[93017:5643534] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
test1.5
test2
test3
```

と出てしまいます。
ソースは下記の通りです。

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var emoji = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
    var button11: UIButton!
    var button12: UIButton!
    var fFastBoot = true
    var fPri = CGFloat(20)
    var ifontSize = 18.0
    var RPath = ""

    // Portrait表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var portraitHeight: CGFloat = 190.0
    private var portraitWidth: CGFloat!

    // Landscape表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var landscapeHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    private var landscapeWidth: CGFloat!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

    }

    var realmPath: String {
        let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.AppGroupKeyboard")
        return containerURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm").path!
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pas = realmPath
        print(pas)

        // Perform custom UI setup here

        ・・・

        let inputText = "か"
        print("test1")
        let realm = try! Realm()
        print("test1.5")
        let results = realm.objects(dic)
            .filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText)
            .sorted("date", ascending: false)
        print("test2")


        for result in results {
            print(result)
        }
        print("test3")
    }
・・・
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それはRealmがシミュレータで実行したときに限り、フレームワークのバージョンチェックのための通信をするのですが、それはiOS 9の制限により失敗していることによるものです。
データが読み込めないこととは何の関係もありません。

そもそも、Realmのファイルパスを

```
var realmPath: String {
    let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.AppGroupKeybora")
    return containerURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm").path!
}
```

としたいはずなのに、

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

と、デフォルト値を使うやり方でRealmを初期化しているのが問題なのではありませんか？

Realmを指定したパスで保存先を指定して初期化するには、イニシャライザのパラメータにファイルパスを渡す必要があります。

```
let realm = try! Realm(path: realmPath)
```

Comment: データが読めるようになりました。本当にありがとうございました。